# Problem in saving folder path using QFileDailog - PYQT

Tags: pyqt5, qfiledialog

I created a button(QPushButton) which helps me to browse and select folder location and save that path into the box(QlinEdit) using PYQT5.
[Here is the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmicS.png)

**Problem**

> I'm able to browse the path and save it to a variable. But when I
> close the program (.py) and run it again then the location path will
> get change(empty). So, I have to browse and save it again and again
> whenever I run the program.

---

Is there any solution or way to just save it once and it will remains the same always ???

Comment: [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html)

Comment: On my system, the last five locations visited are stored in the [file-dialog's history](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#history) and automatically saved in *$HOME/.config/QtProject.conf*. However, I don't use native file-dialogs, so that history may not be available on all platforms (unless you set the [DontUseNativeDialog option](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum)). Anyway, if you don't mind using Qt's built-in dialog, you can try this: `dialog = QFileDialog(); dialog.setDirectory(dialog.history()[-1]); dialog.exec()`.